# Python Traits: pickle list of object, item is set twice

Tags: python, pickle, traits

Basically, I try to pickle and restore a Traits object, which contains a list of objects. 
While restoring, the event notification on changes of the list is fired twice:

```
from enthought.traits.api import Int, HasTraits, List, on_trait_change
import cPickle

class Foo(HasTraits):
    a = Int(1)

class Bar(HasTraits):
    l = List(Foo)
    @on_trait_change('l[]')
    def _l_changed(self):
        for x in self.l:
            print x.a

    def store(self):
        file = open('test_state.pyd', 'w')
        cPickle.dump(self.__getstate__(), file)
        file.close()
    def restore(self):
        file = open('test_state.pyd')
        self.__setstate__(cPickle.load(file))
        file.close()

    b = Bar(l=[Foo()])

    b.store()

    print 'restoring...'

    b.restore()
```

will lead to restoring... 1 1

I think the problem is that pickle does not only pickle the attributes of the object b, but also the object b itself (because of the list).
This problem has also been pointed out here https://mail.enthought.com/pipermail/enthought-dev/2006-December/003707.html, though unanswered.
Then calling cPickle.load(file), it will therefore already create a Bar object, firing the event.
The **setstate** method will then set the pickled data on the current object b, firing the event again.

Any thought on how this could be avoided, i.e. the first event while cPickle.load(file)?